# Include external R script in roxygen2 documentation

Tags: r, roxygen2

When developing packages, I often have R scripts stored in the `inst` directory that produce data objects then included in the package, i.e. stored as `someObj.rda` in the `data` directory.

These objects, in turn, have R scripts with roxygen2 headers for documentation (e.g. someObj.R). 
Ideally, I would like to include a line in the roxygen2 header that sources and formats the script as code, OUTSIDE of examples. Yes, I could copy the lines in, but in the DRY principle, it would be nice to have the documentation include the code automatically.

I have tried the following with no success:

```
rdScript <- function(x) {
  lns <- readLines(x)
  lns <- sprintf("#' \\code{%s}", lns)
  cat(lns, sep = "\n")
}

#' @name someObj
#' @title Some R Bbject
#' @description Some R Object
#' @details
#' Data created with the following script:
#' @eval  rdScript("inst/createCrimeData.R")
#'

NULL
```

And this:

```
rdScript <- function(x) {
  lns <- readLines(x)
  lns <- sprintf("\\code{%s}", lns)
  lns
}

#' @name someObj
#' @title Some R Bbject
#' @description Some R Object
#' @details
#' Data created with the following script:
#' @eval  rdScript("inst/createCrimeData.R")
#'

NULL
```

**Edit in response to arguments against placing these scripts in the `inst`**

While this was not the intention of this question, I would like to make the argument for `inst` being the ideal place for these scripts. This situation comes up for me personally when producing not general-use R packages, but R packages to accompany manuscripts and reproduce analyses. R packages provide an ***ideal*** format for disseminating fully-reproducible analyses. However, often analyses include large datasets that are not needed in entirety. By including a script in `inst`, users can choose (easily) to reproduce the data included in the package BUT are not required recreate the input data for the analysis. It does not make sense to obscure the scripts away.

Comment: What do you mean by "R scripts stored in the inst directory that produce data objects then included in the package". Stuff in /inst is not run, it is copied to the package root

Comment: Correct -- often I include data objects that were themselves created by some script that I do not intend users to run. For reproducibility purposes, I include the script in inst. It would be cool to also include that script in the documentation.

Comment: If you don't intend users to run your script, don't put it in /inst

Comment: I don’t intend the typical user to run the code.

Comment: "R packages provide an ideal format for disseminating fully-reproducible analyses." If it was an ideal format, you wouldn't have to ask this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would agree with [Hong Ooi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/474349/hong-ooi) and say that in general you shouldn't put it in `inst/`; that is copied into the user's installation. I follow the advice in [Hadley Wickham's R Packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html#data-sysdata) and put them in a folder called `data-raw/` (which you then add to `.Rbuildignore`). However, for the use case you further describe in the edits to your question, I can see why you would want to put the script in `inst/` to distribute to your users.

But, on to the problem at hand. You can do this by instead using `@evalRd` and adding the `\details{}` part *in* `rdScript()`. I set up a dummy package `foo` with the file `inst/bar.R` with the following code in it:

```
a <- 5
b <- 8
```

Then I made `R/baz.R` with

```
rdScript <- function(filename, prepend = "") {
    lns <- readLines(filename)
    lns <- paste(sprintf("\\code{%s}", lns), collapse = "\n\n")
    return(paste("\\details{", prepend, "\n", lns, "}", sep = "\n"))
}

#' @name someObj
#' @title Some R Object
#' @description Some R Object
#'
#' @evalRd rdScript("inst/bar.R", "Data was created with the following script:")
NULL
```

After `document()`ing, I get the following in `man/someObj.Rd`:

```
% Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand
% Please edit documentation in R/baz.R
\name{someObj}
\alias{someObj}
\title{Some R Object}
\description{
Some R Object
}
\details{
Data was created with the following script:


\code{a <- 5}

\code{b <- 8}
}
```

which renders in RStudio's help viewer as

[image]

Comment: The issue here is the new line. In the rendered help doc, i.e. running `?someObj` the code does not have newlines rendered.

Comment: @dayne See edits; just need to add some more `"\n"`

Comment: I could have sworn I tried that exact modification with the `\n\n` and it didn't work -- this is what I get for asking questions at night. Nice answer! Also, see my edit regarding the use of inst.

Comment: @dayne In the context you describe in your edit, it makes sense. The question of whether to put in `inst/` or not depends fully on if you want to distribute the script to your users. In this case, it sounds like the answer is "yes," so it makes total sense for you to do that. Glad it helped, cheers!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213379/discussion-between-dayne-and-duckmayr).